# Select multiple Columns dynamically in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried this:

```
a = 'v2'
b = 'v10'

df1[[a]]             #returns the column with the name v2
df1[[a+ "," + b]]    #KeyError: "['v2,v10'] not in index"
```

I also tried different approaches like `a="'v2'" + "," + "'v10'"` but non of it worked. Anyone who can help me get this working?

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I have made myself not clear enough. I have to add:

Let us say I have a function:

```
def foo(*args):
```

and now I want to select all the columns provided within args. My idea was to build a string with

```
for i in args:
    str = i + str
```

and then to select the columns with `df1[[str]]`. For this I have to build a string. Every try to build that string beforehand is not working.

Comment: are you looking for `df[['a', 'b']]` ?

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the columns you wish to select dynamically? I think that will help clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just using `pandasql`

```
import pandasql as ps
q = "SELECT {} FROM df1 ".format(a+','+b)
print(ps.sqldf(q, locals()))
   v2  v10
0   1    2
1   3    4
2   5    6
```

Answer (score 2):

`df1[[a, b]]` gives you a (slice of) the two columns `['v2', 'v10']` of `df1`. while `df1[[a+ "," + b]]` gives you column named `a+ "," + b`, which is `'v2,v10'`, of `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate a string to create the list of columns to select:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]), columns=['v2', 'v10'])

a = 'v2'
b = 'v10'

df1[[a, b]]
```

Output:

```
    v2  v10
0   1   2
1   3   4
2   5   6
```

You could think of it like this too, if you want a variable:

```
c = [a, b]
df1[c]
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is:

```
def test(*args):
    out = df1.filter(items=args)
    return out
print(test('v10', 'v2'))
```

Answer (score -1):

For selecting a list of columns, define them in a list: `["v1", ..., "v10"]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["5004490", "20002075", "15946454"],
     ["5003807", "00601731", "15947894"],
     ["5003808", "00601731", "78945611"]],
    columns=['v1', 'v2', 'v10']
)
print(df)
#         v1        v2       v10
# 0  5004490  20002075  15946454
# 1  5003807  00601731  15947894
# 2  5003808  00601731  78945611

column_name = ["v1", "v10"]
print(df[column_name])
#         v1       v10
# 0  5004490  15946454
# 1  5003807  15947894
# 2  5003808  78945611
```

Hope that help !

Comment: df1[[a]]  selects the column I want. My problem is selecting multiple columns dynamically.